# Can't restore nuget packages from local repository under VS2017

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

I am moving from VS2015 to VS2017.  I keep a local NuGet repository of stuff I'm working on that is used in other projects in a folder "D:\Development\ZNugetFeed".

I'm having to do a restore packages, and under VS2017 even though the file is there in the correct folder, and VS2017 is configured to use it as a repository, I keep getting an error "Unable to find version 'x.x.xxxx.xxxxx' of package 'y'."  It then shows all the locations it says it didn't find it, including the folder it is in.

Has anyone seen this type of problem?

Comment: Try after uncheck all the package sources except the one which has the package.

Comment: Been there, done that.

Comment: Is it working or not?

Comment: No; I've done all sorts of different combinations.

Comment: Try after updating your Package Manager by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173657/package-requires-nuget-client-version-2-12/42175747#42175747

Comment: This is VS2017.  The package manager is the latest 4.2.0.2457.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/43562917/5112433

Comment: Had already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem by installing IIS and the Nuget app, and then pointing VS2017 to the app.