# SendGrid on VS2013?

Tags: c#, nuget, sendgrid

I'm trying install the package `SendGrid` on VS2013 but it doesn't works and throws an exception that I think it happens because the Nuget's version. I made the Nuget's upgrade and it still does not working.

How could I make upgrade of the Nuget on VS2013 ? 
Is there another solution to use SendGrid on VS2013 ?

Trying

```
PM> Install-Package SendGrid
```

Exception

> Install-Package : The 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0' package requires NuGet
>   client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is
>   '2.12.0.817'.
>       At line:1 char:16
>       + Install-Package <<<<  SendGrid
>           + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], NuGetVersionNotSatisfiedException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Did you try any of the options here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26606643/578411

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nuget version not correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26606643/nuget-version-not-correct)